# XOR operation to swap to value without additional variable

Tags: bit-manipulation

I'm breaking my mind to find a good explanation to split two variables with the XOR operation.

The operation is the following:

```
x ^= y # =>                      (x ^ y, y)
y ^= x # => (x ^ y, y ^ x ^ y) = (x ^ y, x)
x ^= y # => (x ^ y ^ x, x)     = (y, x)
```

and my doubt is about the second line, in particular `(x ^ y, y ^ x ^ y) = (x ^ y, x)`  how I can have the result `X` from the operation `y ^ x ^ y`?

I know that y^y = 0, but in the previous case I can not say that y^x^y is equal to x.

What I'm losing here?

[Source](https://florian.github.io/xor-trick/#application-1-in-place-swapping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, xor is commutative and associative, therefore (a xor b) xor c = a xor (b xor c) = a xor (c xor b) = (a xor c) xor b, and in your case that means (x xor y) xor x = (x xor x) xor y = 0 xor y = y.

But this is just a rather pointless programming trick. It only works for integers, it can't be used for floating point numbers, strings, booleans, pointers etc., so it is pointless. It wouldn't pass any code review, so you can't ever use it in real life.

Comment: this part is unclear to me `(x xor y) xor x = (x xor x) xor y`, What happen under the hood? this looks like that the variable will be ordered, but I think is my big fault, right? I'm able to understand how the computer can do it

Comment: This trick only assumes that the operands are Boolean vectors and the operation xor is applied component-wise. The type of the information is irrelevant. So, it works with anything you want. Not working is not what justifies the last sentence. [Reasons that do justify the last sentence are these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Reasons_for_avoidance_in_practice).

Comment: thanks for this good reference, my previous message contains a mistake, I mean that I can not imagine how a computer can do it, but the reference clarify my dubth. Thanks